# How to convert GifDrawable (of Glide 4) into InputStream?

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I want to set Gif as wallpaper, but I want to load online gif from URL and the library I am using is getting input stream of a local gif from a raw directory.

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<GifDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull GifDrawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable> transition) {
            // i want to convert this GifDrawable resource into InputStream
            //InputStream is = ?
        }
    });
```

I don't know just how to do this.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to set Gif as wallpaper and the library i am using is getting inputstream of local gif from raw directory.

Comment: but i want to load online gif from url

Comment: save the gif as a file into the storage. You can easily get InputStream of it after

Comment: ok i ll try and update

Comment: There were explanations of the question written as a comment by the owner and I replaced them in the question.